# How to do rolling calculation based a a subsets of rows

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I am doing rolling mean analysis on a pandas dataframe,

```
R1_Chr_Name distance    count
0   chr1    100 163
1   chr1    101 203
2   chr1    102 194
3   chr1    103 193
4   chr1    104 154
5   chr2    100 150
6   chr2    101 152
7   chr2    102 163
8   chr2    103 161
9   chr2    104 170
10  chr3    100 154
11  chr3    101 160
12  chr3    102 175
13  chr3    103 134
14  chr3    104 151
```

I want to add a column named 'average_count' that will do rolling mean within a subgroup of rows, e.g. do rolling mean of 'count' when column 'R1_Chr_Name' equals to chr1, chr2, ch3 ...,
The disired result should look like:

```
R1_Chr_Name distance    count   average_count
0   chr1    100 163 NaN
1   chr1    101 203 NaN
2   chr1    102 194 186.666667
3   chr1    103 193 196.666667
4   chr1    104 154 180.333333
5   chr2    100 150 NaN
6   chr2    101 152 NaN
7   chr2    102 163 155.000000
8   chr2    103 161 158.666667
9   chr2    104 170 164.666667
10  chr3    100 154 NaN
11  chr3    101 160 NaN
12  chr3    102 175 163.000000
13  chr3    103 134 156.333333
14  chr3    104 151 153.333333
```

Currently I am using the following code and found previous calculations were overwritten:

```
chr_ls = ['chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3']
for chrom in chr_ls:
    df['average_count']=df[df['R1_Chr_Name']==chrom]['count'].rolling(3).mean()
    print(df)

R1_Chr_Name  distance  count  average_count
0         chr1       100    163            NaN
1         chr1       101    203            NaN
2         chr1       102    194            NaN
3         chr1       103    193            NaN
4         chr1       104    154            NaN
5         chr2       100    150            NaN
6         chr2       101    152            NaN
7         chr2       102    163            NaN
8         chr2       103    161            NaN
9         chr2       104    170            NaN
10        chr3       100    154            NaN
11        chr3       101    160            NaN
12        chr3       102    175     163.000000
13        chr3       103    134     156.333333
14        chr3       104    151     153.333333
```

So, how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Check with `groupby`

```
df['ave_count']=df.groupby('R1_Chr_Name')['count'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df
Out[232]: 
   R1_Chr_Name  distance  count   ave_count
0         chr1       100    163         NaN
1         chr1       101    203         NaN
2         chr1       102    194  186.666667
3         chr1       103    193  196.666667
4         chr1       104    154  180.333333
5         chr2       100    150         NaN
6         chr2       101    152         NaN
7         chr2       102    163  155.000000
8         chr2       103    161  158.666667
9         chr2       104    170  164.666667
10        chr3       100    154         NaN
11        chr3       101    160         NaN
12        chr3       102    175  163.000000
13        chr3       103    134  156.333333
14        chr3       104    151  153.333333
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I surely works. I am really confused how reset_index() method, count() works. Need more research.